# How to execute parent element click event before the child element click event

Tags: html, typescript, event-handling

When we click on a child element, it will trigger the child element's click event function first and afterwards the parent element's click event function. How can we execute the parent click event function before the child click event function? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.PosleNazatia');

function toggleElement(elementId) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.PosleNazatia');
  var element = document.querySelector(elementId);

  if (element.style.display === 'block') {
    element.style.display = "none";
    return
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  element.style.display = "block";
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("ContainerForMenu");
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var target = this.getAttribute("data-target");
      toggleElement(target);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="KnopkaWmenu"> 
  <button class="ContainerForMenu"  data-target="#element3">
      <div class="houli">
          <object class="IconFORMenuu" data="photo/Group 1.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
          <span class="textForButtonMenu">
            <a href="#" class="LinkForButton">Business</a>
          </span>
          
        </div>
        <i class="IconForButton"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="PosleNazatia" id="element3">
    <a class="LinkForMenu" href="#">
        <span class="textForLink">GameStop</span>
    </a>
    <a class="LinkForMenu" href="#">
        <span class="textForLink">Moderna</span>
    </a>
    <a class="LinkForMenu" href="#">
        <span class="textForLink">Pfizer</span>
    </a>
    <a class="LinkForMenu" href="#">
        <span class="textForLink">Johnson & Johnson</span>
    </a>
    <a class="LinkForMenu" href="#">
        <span class="textForLink">AstraZeneca</span>
    </a>
    <a class="LinkForMenu" href="#">
        <span class="textForLink">Walgreens</span>
    </a>
    <a class="LinkForMenu" href="#">
        <span class="textForLink">Best Buy</span>
    </a>
    <a class="LinkForMenu" href="#">
        <span class="textForLink">Novavax</span>
    </a>
    <a class="LinkForMenu" href="#">
        <span class="textForLink">SpaceX</span>
    </a>
    <a class="LinkForMenu" href="#">
        <span class="textForLink">Tesla</span>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34430398)